# Can we setup JMS communication without username and password?

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-classic

I am working in a jBoss environment and implemented JMS for enabling asynchronous communication between two modules. But for this I need to add the user by "add-user.sh" script. Then the user information gets saved in application-users.properties and application-roles.properties. Then I need to hardcode this username and password in the MessagePublisher class who will authenticate the user by the following block of code -

```
final static String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
Context context=null;
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, System.getProperty("username", "abcd"));
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, System.getProperty("password", "xyz")); 
context = new InitialContext(env);
```

But I just want to bypass this step of username and password. I know in ActiveMQ it is possible by setting `<simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="true">`Similarly can we do the same thing in JMS?

I found that in the standalone.xml there is an entry -

```
<security-settings>
  <security-setting match="#">
    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
  </security-setting>
</security-settings>
```

I am sure we need to modify this section, but didn't found any reference.

How can we allow an anonymous username to send messages to a JMS queue or topic?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some research I found out the answer.

In the standalone.xml file under the messaging subsystem -
Remove the following lines –

```
<security-settings>
<security-setting match="#">
<permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
<permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
<permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
<permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
</security-setting>
```

Instead add the following line in that same place –

```
<security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
```

Under the remoting subsystem we need to remove the security-realm entry. So remove the line -

```
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
```

And add the line -

```
<connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting"/>
```

With this we can do the following -

```
// Set up the context for the JNDI lookup
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
// username and password are not required
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
//env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
context = new InitialContext(env);

// Create the JMS connection, session, producer, and consumer
// no need to pass the username and password when create connection
//connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("usernme", "password");
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

Thanks
Nirmalya